# Load Image Before Video

Tags: html, css, load

How do I load the phone image before the video loads?

I want the phone image to load before the video embedd.

```
<style>
  div.phone-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 67.5%;
    height: 0;
  }

  div.phone-wrapper iframe {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url(https://www5.cadence.com/rs/070-BII-206/images/phone-mobile-blk-300.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding: 11.9% 15.5% 14.8%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<!-- The script tag should live in the head of your page if at all possible -->
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://play.vidyard.com/embed/v4.js"></script>

<!-- Put this wherever you would like your player to appear -->
<div class="phone-wrapper">
<img
  style="width: 100%; margin: auto; display: block; max-width: 300px;"
  class="vidyard-player-embed"
  src="https://play.vidyard.com/6UxbuQNxGx11T1igjQ16E3.jpg"
  data-uuid="6UxbuQNxGx11T1igjQ16E3"
  data-v="4"
  data-type="inline"
  data-width="300"
/>
</div>
```

I haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can set visibity to your iframe and img styles, and add this JS snippet.

This code will use the *async* and *await* keywords to wait for the phone image to load. once the image has loaded, the code will set the visibility property of the video embed to *visible*.

Here is the edited code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Load Phone Image Before Video</title>
<style>
  div.phone-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 67.5%;
    height: 0;
  }

  div.phone-wrapper iframe {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url(https://www5.cadence.com/rs/070-BII-206/images/phone-mobile-blk-300.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding: 11.9% 15.5% 14.8%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  div.phone-wrapper img {
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 300px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="phone-wrapper">
<img
  style="width: 100%; margin: auto; display: block; max-width: 300px;"
  class="vidyard-player-embed"
  src="https://play.vidyard.com/6UxbuQNxGx11T1igjQ16E3.jpg"
  data-uuid="6UxbuQNxGx11T1igjQ16E3"
  data-v="4"
  data-type="inline"
  data-width="300"
/>
</div>

<script>
async function loadPhoneImage() {
  const phoneImage = document.querySelector(".phone-wrapper img");
  const videoEmbed = document.querySelector(".phone-wrapper iframe");

  await phoneImage.onload;

  videoEmbed.style.visibility = "visible";
}

loadPhoneImage();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```